# API call via Office scripts in MS Excel WebApp

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-scripts

In the Excel WebApp (Office 365) it is possible to place Office Scripts via the "Automate" tab, which is using the JavaScript-syntax and which could automate excel like a VBA-macro, but for the excel WebApp  (Screenshot).

How is it possible to add an API call to an external endpoint (Like a GET request) via this Excel WebApp "Automate" Office Script?
(A scenario would be fetched data from an external API (like weather data) for display in the excel-grid of the excel-webapp).

[image: Screenshot of the excel webapp with office-scripts-code-editor opened]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests to external APIs / URLs can be achieved with `fetch()`

Example:

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  const result = await fetch(uri);
  const json = await result.json();
  
  console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, is there a code-sample available for a POST request as well? Thanks

Comment: Sure, fetch() works the same way it does in the browser—Mozilla's developer docs have some great examples. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options

Answer (score 3):

> Awesome, is there a code-sample available for a POST request as well?

Please refer to the below.

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const param = {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "Test",
        body: "Hello World.",
        userId: 1
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    };
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/", param);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
}
```

Comment: Hi, is this confirmed working? I know that fetch also supports POSTing to an endpoint, however, as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364291/office-scripts-post-request-to-external-api-succeeds-but-reports-as-failed) it doesn't seem to be tht easy.... I have not yet seen a single reference to POSTing something in an official doc

Answer (score 0):

just to confirm, post from @kinuasa gives me an error "Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.". Adding type to the output solves helped - "const json: string = await res.json();"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34853851)